# Drupal: Creating a simple blog?

Tags: drupal, blogs

I'm new to Drupal and trying get my head around it. I'd like to create a simple blog where I have a page that displays blog posts and the number of comments on each posts. Once the blog title or comment number is clicked, the user is taken to the post page. Simple as that.

I'm using Views and CCK, and I was able to create the main blog page, but I have no idea how to give each post its own page which contains comments and a comment form.

I tried searching online with no luck.

Any idea how to do this?

appreciate your help

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In Views, you can select one of the fields you're displaying (best bet: the Title field) and select the "Link this field to its node" option. That'll make it a link to the individual node page, which is where comments etc. live by default.

Answer (score 0):

Your question is quite broad, but you will need to do the following: Create a user node and connect it to the user profile (CCK, nodeprofile and usernode), and a new content type (CCK) for the blog posts (with any custom fields you may want). And then use Views to show the blog posts and profiles of each user. (You can build a view that uses arguments to select user/blog posts and also gives nice urls.)